# How do I control the positon of the menu icon on a page using a material-ui menu?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

By default the menu icon is appearing on the left of the page, but I need it on the right as shown in the attachment.

I have tried styling the div and the icon element, but no luck. I exhaustively searched the internet and I cannot find and answer. Thanks for helping.

Here's my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp";
import Printer from "../SVG/Printer";
import Download from "../SVG/Download";
import Email from "../SVG/Email";

const StyledMenu = withStyles({
  paper: {
    border: "1px solid #d3d4d5"
  }
})(props => (
  <Menu
    elevation={0}
    getContentAnchorEl={null}
    anchorOrigin={{
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "center"
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
      vertical: "top",
      horizontal: "center"
    }}
    {...props}
  />
));

const StyledMenuItem = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      "& .MuiListItemIcon-root, & .MuiListItemText-primary": {
        color: theme.palette.common.white
      }
    }
  }
}))(MenuItem);

const MyClaimedClassmatesOptionMenu = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleDownload = () => {
    alert("You clicked handleDownload");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <KeyboardArrowUpIcon
        aria-controls="customized-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      ></KeyboardArrowUpIcon>
      <StyledMenu
        id="customized-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <StyledMenuItem onClick={handleDownload}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Download />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Download" />
        </StyledMenuItem>
        <StyledMenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Printer />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Print" />
        </StyledMenuItem>
        <StyledMenuItem>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <Email />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Email" />
        </StyledMenuItem>
      </StyledMenu>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyClaimedClassmatesOptionMenu;
```

[image: This the way the page looks with the icon on the left. I need the icon to be on the right]

Answer (score 0):

simple `float-right` should do the trick... this would be my response working from the code you provided...

relevant **css**:

```
.MuiSvgIcon-colorPrimary { float: right; }
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dazuzy)